# PHP flock() behaviour difference on Windows vs Linux

Tags: php, linux, windows

I am executing the same code snippet on a Windows machine and a Linux machine.  Both are running PHP 5.4:

```
$file = "lock.txt";
$fp = fopen($file, "w+");
flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
var_dump(@file_put_contents($file, 'hello' . rand()));
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);
```

On the Windows machine, the `file_put_contents()` operation fails and returns false.  On the Linux machine, it succeeds.

I'm trying to figure out which of these two behaviours is actually correct and how I can standardize the behaviour across both systems (for the record, my goal is to have the `file_put_contents()` fail.  I don't need it to be robust or atomic, I just want it to fail.)

I have seen plenty of other questions about this topic, but they all seem to relate to multiple scripts accessing the same file, which isn't the situation here.

Comment: Both behaviours are correct, they're just different.  Windows supports file sharing modes, and by default when you open a file you are given exclusive access to it.  Linux doesn't do that.  (Note that the flock() function creates an advisory lock, so it would only work if `file_put_contents` called flock() too, which presumably it doesn't.)

Comment: I recommend you rephrase your question (or post a new question) to focus on what you actually want to do: lock the file so that `file_put_contents` will fail, on Linux.  The fact that Windows does what you want by default isn't really relevant to the question.  (A Google search on "linux file lock" suggests that you may be out of luck, but it would be best to obtain expert advice.)

Comment: The end goal was actually less important to me than figuring out what was going on, which is why I phrased the question as I did!  Anyway, I think I understand now.

Answer (score 3):

It appears the documentation for `flock()` does answer this question, albeit not as fully as it could.  The documentation *does* state

> flock() uses mandatory locking instead of advisory locking on Windows

which is clear enough but I was thrown off by the [first comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php#78318) which reads

> Flock utilizes ADVISORY locking only; that is, **other processes** may
> ignore the lock completely

I was interpreting that to mean that my own process would respect the lock implicitly; actually it seems to mean something like, "We assume that--once you're using `flock()` in the first place--you will remember to check the lock's status before any writes, but remember that other programs may not be doing so."

Comment: This is quoted from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) **".... in an advisory way (which means all accessing programs have to use the same way of locking or it will not work)"**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience with writing XML to a file with SimpleXMLElement:asXML() after opening the file with fopen() and locking it with flock(), writing PHP for Windows 10.  The file would be left empty on the Windows machine, while it worked just fine on my Linux machine and would leave the file with the XML document.  I would try just having a separate "lock file" on the Windows machine, open it for reading to get the file descriptor, then lock it either with an exclusive or shared lock, then use your PHP file_get_contents(), asXML(), simpleXML_load_file(), whatever the case may be on the actual file, then unlock the lock file with flock() and close it with fclose().  This works better, I guess, because opening a file for writing with fopen() seems to interfere with those PHP functions on Windows.

So, you would have...

```
   $fd=fopen("lockfile.txt", "r");
   flock($fd, LOCK_EX);
   $text=file_get_contents("myFile");
   $text .= "Add some text.\n";
   file_put_contents("myFile", $text);
   flock($fd, LOCK_UN);
   fclose($fd);

   $fd=fopen("lockfile.txt", "r");
   flock($fd, LOCK_SH);
   $text = file_get_contents("myFile");
   echo $text;
   flock($fd, LOCK_UN);
   fclose($fd);
```

The "lock file" is just there as a traffic light to protect the actual file that is important in the program.  You would need to do it this way in Windows, because theoretically those PHP functions won't operate on a file already opened by fopen(), while you still need a file descriptor as a parameter in flock().

Make sure that "lockfile.txt" or whatever you name it exists!

```
   if (!file_exists("lockfile.txt")){
          $fd = fopen("lockfile.txt", "w");
          fwrite("lockfile.txt", "This lockfile now exists!\n");
          fclose($fd);
   }
```