# Why a second client from the same IP has a 20sec timeout before displaying the page?

Tags: php, apache

## Edit:

I've changed the title from "*Why a second client cannot access the page until the first one's call has finished?*" to "*Why a second client from the same IP has a 20sec timeout before displaying the page?*". **So the reasoning is not the same before all the edits.**

---

here are 2 URLs:
`/home` and `/sleep`.

`/home` displays the homepage

`/sleep` sleeps 10 seconds

---

I have 2 clients:

**Client 1** : `/sleep` -> waits 10 seconds

**Client 1** : `/sleep`, **Client 2** : `/home` -> *Client 1* waits 10 secs, *Client 2* loaded the page instantaneously.

**Client 1** : `/sleep`, **Client 2** : `/sleep` -> *Client 1* waits 10 secs, *Client 2* waits **20** secs

---

Why ? How can I dodge this ?

I would like to display something special if this page is already called by somebody else.

Here is my code:

```
$fileHandler = fopen('process.lock', 'w');
$hasLock = flock($fileHandler, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB);
if (!$hasLock) {
    return('already running'); // it never goes here.
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
    echo nl2br("$i" . PHP_EOL);
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}

flock($fileHandler, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fileHandler);
```

## Edit

What a coincidence. In fact, it returns 'already running' at 20 seconds of waiting time. It means that if I have an infinite loop in the `for`, I would have 'already running' on the **Client 2** but with 20 secs timeout.

I just wonder what timeout it is.

## Edit2

I've done further tests, to proof that it comes from Apache or PHP configuration, not the functions I use:

**Client 1** on `/sleep`:

```
public function sleep() {
    // this is the endpoint of http://127.0.0.1/sleep
    sleep(300);
}
```

Then I edit this file, so that the **Client 2** makes its call on that function:

```
public function sleep() {
    // this is the endpoint of http://127.0.0.1/sleep
    die('hello');
}
```

If I run my both clients from 5 secs interval (the time to make the changes to the file), the second client stills wait 20 seconds before printing `hello`.

## Edit3

**Client 1** : `127.0.0.1/sleep` -> waits 10 seconds

**Client 2** : `192.168.0.10/sleep` -> waits 10 seconds without delay

I conclude that the problem is from the request from the same IP. Why ?

Comment: How are apache and PHP configured?

Comment: @max it's a basic configuration. I've just added my VHost in Apache (2.4) and using `max_execution_time 0` in PHP (5.5.12). You can reproduce the problem with the most basic configuration. I'm on Windows (10 if it matters.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php), `flock()` on [windows performs Mandatory locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#In_Microsoft_Windows).
This means that the system checks the lock for you on file operations including fopen.

On Linux it would perform advisory locking which requires the processes accessing the file to cooperate by all attempting to acquire the lock through calls to `flock()`.

The Windows variant allows you to lock once and block out all other programs, including those that have no knowledge of your code.

Your second client is blocking on the `fopen()` call waiting for the lock to free up.

Edit: I do realize that I have not actually answered your first question: how to avoid this. An easy fix would be to move your code to a linux server if that is a possibility for you. Otherwise I advise you search how to do advisory locking on windows.

**Related question:** [PHP flock() behaviour difference on Windows vs Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534748/php-flock-behaviour-difference-on-windows-vs-linux)

Comment: No, it does not block on `fopen()`. I will edit my question with a proof, but for example, the first time I call `/sleep`, I change the source code and tell at the first line `die('hello')`, and with the second client, it takes 20 secs to load before displaying `hello`.

Comment: Then it seems that your problem is that Apache is taking exactly 20 seconds to serve client 2 if client 1 sent a request first, regardless of client 1 having been served yet or not, is that correct?


Do you have that behavior when using two separate machines for client 1 and client 2?

You might want to try the same code on nginx to confirm/infirm the problem being Apache related.